# VS Code can't install the Go tools

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I try to start using Go in VSCode. I've installed Go as well as Git and created a project in Code, containing a single `.go` file.

When I type something, VSCode warns me that tools like `golint` are missing and prompts me to install them. I click on "Install all".

Then the console shows this :

```
Installing 10 tools
  gocode
  gopkgs
  go-outline
  go-symbols
  guru
  gorename
  godef
  goreturns
  golint
  gotests

Installing gocode SUCCEEDED
Installing gopkgs SUCCEEDED
Installing go-outline SUCCEEDED
Installing go-symbols FAILED
Installing guru FAILED
Installing gorename FAILED
Installing godef SUCCEEDED
Installing goreturns FAILED
Installing golint FAILED
Installing gotests FAILED

6 tools failed to install.

go-symbols:
Error: Command failed: C:\Go\bin\go.exe get -u -v github.com/newhook/go-symbols
github.com/newhook/go-symbols (download)
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil": found meta tag main.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/tools (download)
# cd C:\Users\user\go\src\golang.org\x\tools; git pull --ff-only
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
package golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil: exit status 128
github.com/newhook/go-symbols (download)
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil": found meta tag main.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/tools (download)
# cd C:\Users\user\go\src\golang.org\x\tools; git pull --ff-only
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
package golang.org/x/tools/go/buildutil: exit status 128

guru:
Error: Command failed: C:\Go\bin\go.exe get -u -v golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru": found meta tag main.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/tools (download)
# cd C:\Users\user\go\src\golang.org\x\tools; git pull --ff-only
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
package golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru: exit status 128
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru": found meta tag main.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/tools (download)
# cd C:\Users\user\go\src\golang.org\x\tools; git pull --ff-only
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
package golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru: exit status 128

gorename:
Error: Command failed: C:\Go\bin\go.exe get -u -v golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename": found meta tag main.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/tools (download)
# cd C:\Users\user\go\src\golang.org\x\tools; git pull --ff-only
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
package golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename: exit status 128
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename": found meta tag main.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/tools (download)
# cd C:\Users\user\go\src\golang.org\x\tools; git pull --ff-only
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
package golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename: exit status 128

goreturns:
Error: Command failed: C:\Go\bin\go.exe get -u -v sourcegraph.com/sqs/goreturns
Fetching https://sourcegraph.com/sqs/goreturns?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://sourcegraph.com/sqs/goreturns?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "sourcegraph.com/sqs/goreturns": found meta tag main.metaImport{Prefix:"sourcegraph.com/sqs/goreturns", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://github.com/sqs/goreturns"} at https://sourcegraph.com/sqs/goreturns?go-get=1
sourcegraph.com/sqs/goreturns (download)
github.com/sqs/goreturns (download)
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/imports?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/imports?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/tools/imports": found meta tag main.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/imports?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/imports": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/tools (download)
# cd C:\Users\user\go\src\golang.org\x\tools; git pull --ff-only
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
package golang.org/x/tools/imports: exit status 128
Fetching https://sourcegraph.com/sqs/goreturns?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://sourcegraph.com/sqs/goreturns?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "sourcegraph.com/sqs/goreturns": found meta tag main.metaImport{Prefix:"sourcegraph.com/sqs/goreturns", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://github.com/sqs/goreturns"} at https://sourcegraph.com/sqs/goreturns?go-get=1
sourcegraph.com/sqs/goreturns (download)
github.com/sqs/goreturns (download)
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/imports?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/imports?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/tools/imports": found meta tag main.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/imports?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/imports": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/tools (download)
# cd C:\Users\user\go\src\golang.org\x\tools; git pull --ff-only
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
package golang.org/x/tools/imports: exit status 128

golint:
Error: Command failed: C:\Go\bin\go.exe get -u -v github.com/golang/lint/golint
github.com/golang/lint (download)
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata": found meta tag main.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/tools (download)
# cd C:\Users\user\go\src\golang.org\x\tools; git pull --ff-only
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
package golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata: exit status 128
github.com/golang/lint (download)
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata": found meta tag main.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/tools (download)
# cd C:\Users\user\go\src\golang.org\x\tools; git pull --ff-only
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
package golang.org/x/tools/go/gcexportdata: exit status 128

gotests:
Error: Command failed: C:\Go\bin\go.exe get -u -v github.com/cweill/gotests/...
github.com/cweill/gotests (download)
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/imports?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/imports?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/tools/imports": found meta tag main.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/imports?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/imports": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/tools (download)
# cd C:\Users\user\go\src\golang.org\x\tools; git pull --ff-only
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
package golang.org/x/tools/imports: exit status 128
github.com/cweill/gotests (download)
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools/imports?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools/imports?go-get=1 (status code 200)
get "golang.org/x/tools/imports": found meta tag main.metaImport{Prefix:"golang.org/x/tools", VCS:"git", RepoRoot:"https://go.googlesource.com/tools"} at https://golang.org/x/tools/imports?go-get=1
get "golang.org/x/tools/imports": verifying non-authoritative meta tag
Fetching https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1
Parsing meta tags from https://golang.org/x/tools?go-get=1 (status code 200)
golang.org/x/tools (download)
# cd C:\Users\user\go\src\golang.org\x\tools; git pull --ff-only
fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
package golang.org/x/tools/imports: exit status 128
```

Some tools are able to install, others are not. I can't do anything about the `Not a git repository` error because it's an automated process and I'm not the one typing the git commands.

I tried installing the tools separately in PowerShell and I get the same errors. My go directory is created (in `%USERPROFILE%\go`) and the `GOPATH` is set correctly.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It looks like it's complaining due to `C:\Users\user\go\src\golang.org\x\tools` being not a git repo, so it can't update whatever is in it.

Assuming you didn't put your own code in that dir, try removing it and then running again.

If you look at the docs for the Go plugin, and scroll all the way to the bottom, it shows the commands to run if you want to manually install/upgrade the stuff the plugin needs.

Specifically, taken from [their github repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-go#tools-this-extension-depends-on), you can just run this from a cmd.exe prompt.

```
go get -u -v github.com/nsf/gocode
go get -u -v github.com/rogpeppe/godef
go get -u -v github.com/zmb3/gogetdoc
go get -u -v github.com/golang/lint/golint
go get -u -v github.com/lukehoban/go-outline
go get -u -v sourcegraph.com/sqs/goreturns
go get -u -v golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gorename
go get -u -v github.com/tpng/gopkgs
go get -u -v github.com/newhook/go-symbols
go get -u -v golang.org/x/tools/cmd/guru
go get -u -v github.com/cweill/gotests/...
go get -u -v golang.org/x/tools/cmd/godoc
go get -u -v github.com/fatih/gomodifytags
```

Comment: I removed everything in the `%GOPATH%\*` dirs that was not a project of myself, relaunched VSCode and asked to "Install all" and the installation is going without problems. Thank you.

Comment: Probably caused by having used multiple versions of Go.

Answer (score 3):

**Solution:**  Just Exit the app & Restart the application as Admin (Run as Administrator). It'll work fine & every module/dependency will be installed Successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You might be running an old version of Go.
Try removing your version and install the latest version from Go's site.