# Error in installing golang plug-ins in vscode

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I wanted to install some golang plug-ins for VSCode in Linux. After installing go and vscode extensions, VScode prompted to install some go extensions. It failed with errors. Looking into the logs I noticed that

```
go get -v github.com/sqs/goreturns
```

returns this error message:

```
go/internal/gcimporter
# go/internal/gcimporter
/usr/local/go/src/go/internal/gcimporter/support.go:16:6: errorf redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/go/internal/gcimporter/bimport.go:165:36
/usr/local/go/src/go/internal/gcimporter/support.go:20:7: deltaNewFile redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/go/internal/gcimporter/bimport.go:300:23
/usr/local/go/src/go/internal/gcimporter/support.go:23:6: fakeFileSet redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/go/internal/gcimporter/bimport.go:335:6
/usr/local/go/src/go/internal/gcimporter/support.go:28:23: (*fakeFileSet).pos redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/go/internal/gcimporter/bimport.go:340:6
/usr/local/go/src/go/internal/gcimporter/support.go:59:2: fakeLines redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/go/internal/gcimporter/bimport.go:371:2
/usr/local/go/src/go/internal/gcimporter/support.go:60:2: fakeLinesOnce redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/go/internal/gcimporter/bimport.go:372:2
/usr/local/go/src/go/internal/gcimporter/support.go:63:6: chanDir redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/go/internal/gcimporter/bimport.go:574:21
/usr/local/go/src/go/internal/gcimporter/support.go:78:5: predeclared redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/go/internal/gcimporter/bimport.go:972:5
/usr/local/go/src/go/internal/gcimporter/support.go:124:6: anyType redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/go/internal/gcimporter/bimport.go:1018:6
/usr/local/go/src/go/internal/gcimporter/support.go:126:18: anyType.Underlying redeclared in this block
        previous declaration at /usr/local/go/src/go/internal/gcimporter/bimport.go:1020:6
/usr/local/go/src/go/internal/gcimporter/support.go:126:18: too many errors
```

I looked up these questions, but did not find my answer:

[VS Code can't install the Go tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43018667/vs-code-cant-install-the-go-tools)

[VS Code can't install the Go tools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43018667/vs-code-cant-install-the-go-tools)

[Downloading and installing Visual Studio Code Go dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58835633/downloading-and-installing-visual-studio-code-go-dependencies)

I appreciate any advice.

ps. this is my first question here, so apology in advance if it miss required info.

Comment: Have you installed a new version of Go without removing the previous version first?

Comment: @Adrian thanks for your quick response. Yes, I guess you are right, I had it installed a while back, because I used a tool that was based on go. May I ask how can I remove the old one?

Comment: `rm -rf /usr/local/go`